# Create string of words into an array with punctuation included

Tags: php

Say I have an input such as:

```
$input = "This is some sample input, it's not complex. ";
$input .="But does contain punctuation such as full stops / back-slashes / etc";
$array = arrayFunction($input);
```

My question is this: What would I need to do in `arrayFunction` for `$array` to equal the below:

```
$array = array(
    0 =>  "This",
    1 =>  "is",
    2 =>  "some",
    3 =>  "sample",
    4 =>  "input",
    5 =>  ",",
    6 =>  "it's",
    7 =>  "not",
    8 =>  "complex",
    9 =>  ".",
    10 =>  "But",
    11 =>  "does",
    12 =>  "contain",
    13 =>  "punctuation",
    14 =>  "such",
    15 =>  "as",
    16 =>  "full",
    17 =>  "stops",
    18 =>  "/",
    19 =>  "back-slashes",
    20 =>  "etc",
);
```

I had been doing the below

```
function arrayFunction($input)
{
    $explode = explode( " ", $input );
    $output  = array();
    foreach ( $explode as $word )
    {
        $output[] = trim( \String::lower( preg_replace('/[^\w|\s|-]+/', '', $word ) ) );
    }

    return $output;
}
```

Which worked fine for my needs, but now I need the output to contain the punctuation so that I can pass the following test:

```
$input  = "This is some sample input, it's not complex.";
$input .= "But does contain punctuation such as full stops/back-slashes/etc";
$array  = arrayFunction($input);

$test  = implode(' ', $array);
if ($test == $input) {
  echo 'PASS';
} else {
  echo 'FAIL';
}
```

Thanks.

**edit** The way I am thinking of doing this is by exploding by spaces and then looping over that result and further splitting by punctuation.

**edit** Thanks to the accepted answer below I was able to rewrite my code to something that worked. For those interested it can be seen here https://gist.github.com/carbontwelve/6639350

Comment: So you want a function that is reversed by `implode`? And you are already using `explode` in your current code? What else is there to say?

Comment: Out of interest, what's wrong with `strtolower()` ? What does `\String::lower()` do?

Comment: There is nothing out of the box that will also explode the , and ., you will need to write a custom function for that.

Comment: @Jon the input may not always have spaces between what I am wanting within the array. For example `stops/back-slashes/etc` and `input,` should also be split as seperate elements in the output of `arrayFunction`

Comment: The array you've posted won't pass that test. There would be a space on both sides of the `,` and `.`

Comment: @SmokeyPHP `String::lower` is a class wrapper for `strtolower` @Chevi I know that. That is why I was asking if anyone had any suggestions before I wrote one.

Comment: @SmokeyPHP I have no idea if [**this**](https://kenai.com/nonav/projects/nette-gpslink/sources/subversion/content/nette_gpslink.pythia.cz/nette_libs/Nette/String.php?rev=2) is the same class, but it seems it's shorthand for `mb_strtolower($string, 'UTF-8')`

Comment: @Paulpro As well as the fact that everything would be lowercase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will produce your desired array:

```
function arrayFunction($input) {
    return preg_split('/(\s|[\.,\/])/', $input, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
}
```

However because you want to pass the test you will need to know where the spaces are, so I could suggest `'/([\s\.,\/])/'` as your regular expression, but then you would need to strip the empty values to get your desired array. Also to pass the test using the suggested regex you would need to do `$test  = implode("", $array);` without the space.

Comment: Thank you, I don't know much regex - but this has helped me. Looks like a better solution to the one I had begun to write :)

Comment: @carbontwelve You might want to add `:`, `;`, `!` and `?` as well, as they're all common punctuations.

Comment: Putting characters between the square brackets will capture them. So as @h2ooooooo suggested you might want to add more punctuation...  `'/([\s\.,\/:;!?])/'` would accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

For test use lower function too

```
if (\String::lower($test) == \String::lower($input)) {
  echo "PASS";
}
```

Also for check make output for $test and $input string and compare it visual